# About Pion decaying into two photons

Tags: particle-physics, photons, collision, pions

Pion decays to 2 photons. If 1000 such pions with their energies ranging from 1 MeV to 1 GeV, decay, then, how can we plot the graph between the angle with which photons get emitted in different direction with their momentum? Is it possible to draw graph for the angle vs momentum of the pion?

Comment: In the rest frame of the pion, the photons are emitted uniformly and back to back. Transform.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529947/relativistic-difference-of-angle-between-two-inertial-frame?rq=1) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432427/how-to-measure-angles-in-minkowsky-space-and-how-do-they-transform).

Answer (score 1):

In this bubble chamber picture the two photon decay with the mass of the pi0 is seen .

[image: bblpi0][image: bblpi0sketch]

> The two rather faint pairs in this picture originate from the same point, where a $π0$ decayed into two photons .

The red lines on the right pick up the two electron positron pairs. The momentum of the electrons and positrons can be determined by the curvature, ( their mass from the ionisation of the tracks) . The addition of the [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) gives a four vector that has the mass of the $π0$. If you follow the links you will see that this is a famous picture that clinched the discovery of $Ω^-$.

You ask

> Is it possible to draw graph for the angle vs momentum of the pion?

It will depend on the interactions  involved. If you can get many such $Ω^-$ decays
you can get a plot, though I do not see that it would tell us more than to define the decay of the $Ξ^0$  . In general the distributions would depend on the specific interaction that gave rise to a  $π0$ .